# DFA: Can the set of States Q be empty by definition?

Tags: terminology, automata, finite-automata

Can the set of states Q be empty by definition?

I was wondering about this question when doing exercises in the pumping lemma for finite automaton.

Comment: Look at the definition of a DFA you have. Does it allow Q to be empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a DFA - no, because the definition includes a *single* initial state $q_0$, which means that $q_0\in Q$, and therefore $Q\neq \emptyset$.

In an NFA, however, this is indeed possible.

Comment: Thanks that was aldo my expectation after reading the wiki, but wasn't sure.

Comment: Note that (as the comment above says), this depends on the exact definition on DFA and NFA. It doesn't really matter, automata without states accept the (rather uninteresting) language $\varnothing$...